# How Do I Add a variable amount of Time to a Datetime variable in Ruby and/or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an events table in my database, which stores a start field (datetime) and a duration field (integer) as well as a unit field (string - Minutes, Hours or Days). In order to derive the end date, I need to add the duration (according to units) to the start. Something like this...

```
@end = @event.start + (@event.duration).(@event.unit)
```

I'm just not sure how to accomplish this in Ruby/Rails.

Comment: What are units stored as? Strings.  Something like minutes.  You could possibly use eval. But is is possible to standardize and change db to store duration in only 1 unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is:

```
@event.duration.public_send(@event.unit.downcase)
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I can't mark it as the answer for another 5 minutes though. Thanks!

Comment: @unclesol dude you even didn't marked it after more than 1 hour :P

Comment: Be careful sending arbitrary strings!  You need to make sure your DB is locked down to only allow the unit strings you want.  For example, a hacker could potentially set the units to '~' converting your duration to a negative number and travel back in time.  It's best to whitelist this at the database level.  It's a good idea to pretend to be a malicious user and see what security holes are in your code.

Comment: If they were able to set the unit to 'exabytes' that could end up w/ some interesting large numbers :)

Comment: Fortunately, this process is run after the data is entered into the database, and the model validations make sure the data is valid when they are entered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, you may want to store the duration in minutes (as an integer possibly) in your DB or another similar unit and then convert to days or hours for display.

This would make it easier to whitelist the units when storing the data from the user and set up validations to make sure your data is valid.

Also, this will give you extra flexibility, so you can easily have a duration of 1 day 3 hours and 15 minutes if you want to (1,635 minutes) and it will give you the ability to easily sort the events by duration if you want.